# How to add rich textbox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to add rich text box in asp.net for adding multiline data in text box

Answer (score 1):

You can use this below code for multiline textboxes,

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtBox" TextMode="multiline" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP:TextBox and set property TextMode="multiLine" Rows="2" to use multi line text box.